# Why is it possible to instantiate an interface?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ienumerable

I have never before seen the following `crazy` syntax, which can be used in the middle of a function:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/convert-foreach-linq?view=vs-2019
    // How is this declaration possible?
    IEnumerable<int> crazy()
    {
        foreach (var num in Enumerable.Range(1, 5))
        {
            yield return num + 20;
        }
    }

    foreach (var thing in crazy())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(thing);
    }
}
```

I am very experienced with creating my own IEnumerable classes and using `yield return`.  But I have never seen a combo declaration-implementation in the middle of a method like the above `crazy()` demonstrates.  Is it some kind of lambda?  If yes, why does it not follow lambda syntax?  Is it a concrete type?  What concrete type?  Struct?  Class? Is it literally a named function declaration in the middle of a method declaration?  Since when was that possible?

I tried this with .Net Core 3.1, but apparently this syntax isn't very new.

Comment: This is just a [Local Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions). Been supported since C# 7.0.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes.

Comment: There are 2 things here, Firstly its a local function, secondly its an iterator method

Comment: You are not instantiating anything - it's just return type.